# 180 degree bone rotation stutter problem - chained Action & Driver rotation

Tags: animation, drivers, 2d, actions

There are a number of posts referencing 180 degree stutter/flipping issues and resolving them by using a driver in-place of a modifier/constraint - which seems to work OK for a 1-to-1 relationship. However - I have a case where a bone rotation is being driven by another bone rotation which in-turn is being driven by an action controlled by a master bone rotation.

I have a vehicle (*mock up shown*) with a small wheel, a big wheel and a control stick. When the stick rotates left/right the vehicle moves (translates) left/right and the wheels rotate left/right.

[image: Big Wheeler]

[**Small Wheel**] <--{*driver x 1.2*}-- [**Big Wheel**]  <--{*action*}--  [**Control Lever**]

The Small wheel is driven 20% faster than the rotation of the big wheel - with a simple driver expression: var * 1.2. If I rotate the Big Wheel bone manually the Small Wheel bone rotates correctly without issue.

The Big Wheel is driven via an Action which also moves the vehicle, which is controlled by a master Control Lever bone.

The Big Wheel visually rotates correctly when manipulated by the Control Lever, however - the Small Wheel now exhibits a stutter when the big wheel passes 180 degrees.

I know I can work-around this by using a driver for both wheels, or by using an action for both wheels - both driven by the control lever, however I am trying to replicate existing behaviour in another application - which this configuration is based on.